# Is there a solution to this dead end I seem to have found in excel? match-index to input cell references in complex excel function

Tags: excel

My issue is that I'm creating a worksheet for data entry for specific categorical data that is stratified. Cell A1 will be a city name, B2,B7, and B11 will be different offices, C3:C6, C8:C10, and C12:C16 will all be different names of employees in each office.

I have a crazy complex function in base excel which I can use to always return the correct office for the employee; for example if I were looking up the office for the employee in C4 I would only need to input B4 and C5 into the function.

My problem is that it seems to only work if I manually enter the cell references into the function. I want to do a match index to find the name, then apply the required cells (to the left and below) to this function. Does this make sense? I'm very sorry this is my first post on here and it may not be clear.

below is the function I'm using to fill the city info for each name. I want to replace L18 and M19 with whatever coordinates are below and to the left of a specific written name. I assumed you would use a match-index, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
=INDIRECT(TEXT(LARGE((TEXT(ROW(A1:L18),"00")&TEXT(COLUMN(A1:L18),"00"))*(((A1:L18<>"")*(COLUMN(M19)-1-COLUMN(A1:L18)+ROW(M19)-1-ROW(A1:L18)))=SMALL(IF(((A1:L18<>"")*(COLUMN(M19)-1-COLUMN(A1:L18)+ROW(M19)-1-ROW(A1:L18)))<>0,COLUMN(M19)-1-COLUMN(A1:L18)+ROW(M19)-1-ROW(A1:L18)),1)),1),"R00C00"),0)
```

L18 and M19 Change as you're finding the value for M18.

I know this could be done easier with Macros, but there are specific constraints on macros for this issue.

Comment: Better yet, mock up some data and expected output and post as plain text so we may copy paste to test our formula.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your set up you can use:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("zzz",$B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E3,C:C,0))))
```

To return the correct Office.

[image]